# Make browser interpret txt as html

Tags: javascript, html

if I add an iframe inside a page and make the src="temp.txt" how can I make the browser interpret it as HTML instead of only displaying the content of "temp.txt"?

Comment: Why does it have the .txt extension if it is actually HTML? It’s not really illegal, just as you could name your GIF file using the .pdf or .doc extension, but it’s not practically sensible.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers learn the MIME type of the file from what the web server tells the browser it is. Generally, web servers are configured so that .txt files are plain text files, and that the browser shouldn't try to interpret any markup in the file.

What you want is for the browser to get the mime type of "text/html". Three ways to do this;

1) Set the filename to temp.htm, this is the easiest

2) Change the web server so that txt files are now html files. In apache for example, you can add a line to httpd.conf that looks something like

```
AddType text/html .txt
```

and remove the line that looks like

```
AddType text/plain .txt
```

I wouldn't recommend this path, as this is a global change. You can try adding this to your .htaccess file in the directory your code resides in as well.

3) Use a dynamic language like PHP to set the file's mime type in transit. For example in PHP:

```
header('Content-type: text/html');
```

and then read the file to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you don't want/have-access-to/permission to manipulate Apache files
and your `.txt` file is at the same domain where your page is
you can access `<iframe>`'s `.textContent` and
replace `<body>`'s `.innerHTML` with it:

say you have an `<iframe>` in `<body>`:

`<iframe id="frame01" src="afile.txt" width="550" height="400"></iframe>`,

and say you have `afile.txt` file in same directory:

```
<p>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</p>
<p>Date: Sat, 13 Apr 2013 16:46:15 GMT</p>
<p>Server: Apache</p>
<p>Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Mar 2013 12:57:30 GMT</p>
<p>Accept-Ranges: bytes</p>
<p>Content-Length: 216469</p>
<p>Connection: close</p>
<p>Content-Type: image/jpeg</p>
```

you can replace page content by running this:

```
//
window.onload =
function () {
  var frame = document.getElementById("frame01");
  document.body.innerHTML =
    frame.contentWindow.document.body.textContent;
};
//
//
```

and output page shold look like:

---

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Date: Sat, 13 Apr 2013 16:46:15 GMT

Server: Apache

Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Mar 2013 12:57:30 GMT

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Content-Length: 216469

Connection: close

Content-Type: image/jpeg

---

with htm tags parsed.