# URL "http://.../js/myscript.js" fetches the source for myscript.js. Why doesn't it run the script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I enter a URL like "http://.../js/script_name.js" in my browser it returns the source for the script.  I would like the server to run the script and return the result. I assume that server is using node.js.

Comment: Please read a tutorial on how to setup node.js on a server. This topic is too broad for StackOverflow unless you specify a specific problem you have setting up the system

Comment: Because the server precises a `Content-Type` along with the file, that should be `application/javascript` for js files if the server is set properly. Browsers execute as HTML for specific values, for example `text/html`. Another question? Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19697279/7393478) for some hints

Comment: Displaying the public source code of a script in a browser, and running this script on a server are two completely different things. If you want to run a script on a server, of course you need to have access to this server, upload files to it, run a webserver on it, etc.

Comment: If that script is designed to run in a browser, then you can insert a `<script>` tag that points to that URL into a vanilla web page and then load that web page into the browser.  That will cause the web page to load and run the script.  If you're trying to run that script in node.js, then you don't use a browser for that.  You fetch the script and run it locally with a local installation of nodejs.

Comment: @Kaddath - This isn't likely a content-type issue.  It's because a top level link in a browser is not executed, even if it's a script type.  Instead, it is displayed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Typing a url with the name of a file will just display the content inside the file. Imagine it like copying a path to a file on your computer, pasting that path in your browser and you will be able to read the file, but it won't be executed. It's the same thing. Actually running it, you'll have to do that in your code.